# C++ Pass a member function to another class

Tags: c++

I'm trying to make a simple callback in C++ but I'm having issues doing it as I want to.

Essentially I want something like this:

```
class A{
   void A::AddCallback(void (*callBackFunction)(string)){
      /*Code goes here*/
   }
}
```

And class B

```
#include "A.h"
class B{
   B::B(){
      A childObject;
      childObject(MyCallBackFunction);   
   }
   B::MyCallBackFunction(string arg){
      /*Code goes here*/
   }
}
```

I know that usually you would want to define the header of `AddCallback` with something like `B::callBackFunction` but I do need to import `A` in `B` so I it would be awkward to have both classes import each other. I know I've seen this before but I cant get the syntax right

Comment: The last part suggests you want to know how to solve circular dependency issues as well; if so, see the ends of these answers: http://stackoverflow.com/a/628079/5386374 & http://stackoverflow.com/a/4757718/5386374  [Specifically: If A.h doesn't need to know B's internal details, forward declare `B` in `A.h`, `#include "B.h"` in `A.cpp`, & `#include "A.h"` in `B.h`.  If B.h doesn't need to know A's, forward declare `A` in `B.h`, `#include "A.h"` in `B.cpp`, & `#include "B.h"` in `A.h`.  Or both: forward declare `A` in `B.h`, forward declare `B` in `A.h`, & put `#include`s in the `.cpp` files.]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is one option using a static member function:

```
#include <string>

struct A
{
    void AddCallback(void (*cb)(std::string));
};

struct B
{
    A a;

    B() { a.AddCallback(&B::MyFun); }

    static void MyFun(std::string);
};
```

If you want a non-static member function, then you first need to decide on which *instance* of `B` you want the member function to be invoked. For example, to invoke it on the object whose constructor registers the callback:

```
#include <functional>
#include <string>

struct A
{
    void AddCallback(std::function<void(std::string)>);
};

struct B
{
    A a;

    B() { a.AddCallback(std::bind(&B::MyFun, this, std::placeholders::_1)); }

    void MyFun(std::string);
};
```

Answer (score -1):

you must call   void A::AddCallback and pass callback instead of passing argument in childObject(MyCallBackFunction);